# Cannot use "this" in a static content in android

Tags: java, android

I am using simple list adapter in my android application

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, jsonParseList , R.layout.list_view, 
                            new String[] {"conv_title","content"}, 
                            new int[] { R.id.conv_title, R.id.content });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the above code in the place of `this` it shows `this` cannot use in a static content. Why?

```
public class Json extends Activity {
    static HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    static ListView listView;
    //ArrayList<String> jsonParseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Jsonparser jsonparser;
    enter code here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.json_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        jsonparser = new Jsonparser();
        jsonparser.execute("");
        Log.e("List Activity", "" + jsonParseList);
    }

    public static HttpURLConnection openConnection() throws Exception {
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    " place ur url");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-encoded");
            urlConnection
                    .setRequestProperty(
                            "Content-Length",
                            ""
                                    + Integer
                                            .toString("place ur url"
                                                    .getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("place ur url");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new Exception("Server not responding");
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new Exception("Connection Time Out");
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException unknownHostException) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new Exception("unknownHostException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new Exception("Error Occured");
        }
        return urlConnection;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> jsonParseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> jsonParsing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        JSONArray array;

        try {
            try {
                urlConnection = openConnection();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            if (buffer.toString() != null) {
                try {
                    array = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String conv_title = jsonObject.getString("conv_title");
                        String content = jsonObject.getJSONObject("first_post")
                                .getString("content");
                        String creator = jsonObject.getJSONObject("first_post")
                                .getJSONObject("creator").getString("name");

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        //map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                        map.put("conv_title", jsonObject.getString("conv_title"));
                        map.put("content", jsonObject.getString("content"));
                        map.put(conv_title, conv_title);
                        map.put(content, content);
                        Log.e("List Values", conv_title);
                        Log.e("List Values", content);

                        jsonParseList.add("conv_title "+"content");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, jsonParseList , R.layout.list_view, 
                            new String[] {"conv_title","content"}, 
                            new int[] { R.id.conv_title, R.id.content });

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonParseList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class Jsonparser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return jsonUtil.jsonParsing();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
                jsonParseList = result;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well presumably you're doing that from a static method. What do you *expect* the value of `this` to be in that case? It's not clear how much you understand about what `static` means.

Comment: next time please show us the method signature, so it would be easier for other to answer your questions

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Using

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, jsonParseList , R.layout.list_view, new String[] {"conv_title","content"}, new int[] { R.id.conv_title, R.id.content });
```

Use like

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClassName.this, jsonParseList , R.layout.list_view, new String[] {"conv_title","content"}, new int[] { R.id.conv_title, R.id.content });
```

Comment: given that the error given suggests a use in a static method, your solution is unlikely to work. What you suggest would work in the context of a Nested or Anonymous inner class, but not in a static context.

Comment: what does `ClassName.this` means?

Comment: @Joy Helina: still its not accepting..it shows red lines under the code..

Answer (score 2):

`this` keyword refers to the current object of a class. So it is related to an object. But static methods are related to class. so you can not use `this` in a static context

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `this` in a static method or field, as `this` refers to the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible to say, since you're not showing the surrounding code.

Typically, `this` refers to the object the executing method belongs to; you can only use it inside actual methods.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods will not have any instance of the class. `this` is a current class's object. So  `this` cannot be used in static methods.

```
new SimpleAdapter(getApplication(), jsonParseList , R.layout.list_view, 
                    new String[] {"conv_title","content"}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.conv_title, R.id.content });
```

Try to use this way.

I hope I explained little bit clearlly.

Comment: Then what i have to put in that place.please suggest..

Comment: still it shows red mark under getApplication()..

Answer (score 0):

this refers to an `instance of an object` whereas `static` `methods` are `Class` methods , for more details see `Class Members`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this that way. Your solution is:

1. Create a static field and initiate onCreate.
2. Use that later in your static content.

Refer to this:

```
  static Context thisContext;

  onCreate(.....){
      thisContext = this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" refers to the current instance of the class the method is called.
A static method is called from the class itself so "this" cannot be used in that context.

One Solution:

Don't make those method static and work with an instance of that class.